# Deployment update after jhipster gae deprecation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, jhipster

Deployment in GCP is explained here: https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/#deploying-microservices-to-google-app-engine but now that jhipster gae is deprecated, the whole thing is outdated and the way to do it would be really helpful.

Is there any video where the whole process is explained? Something for somebody who has never deployed on Google Cloud.

Thanks

Comment: We dropped support for Google App Engine because no one was maintaining it. It should be as simple as deploying a Spring Boot app.

Comment: Thanks Matt, do you have (or know of) a video where the whole process is explained (even it is old)? Thanks

Comment: No, I do not know of a video. I never tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks Matt (for your book and everything)... And Google does not pay a bounty to anyone who can do such a video, so they can sell their GCP? These instructions are obsolete:  https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/#deploying-microservices-to-google-app-engine. Is there anybody at Jhipster who can create the new ones (besides you)?